# Incompatible types with return value of string void java

Tags: java

I get the errors when I try and run my code

Project1.java:5: incompatible types
found   : void
required: java.lang.String
        String creditcard=mainintro();
                                   ^
Project1.java:14: cannot return a value from method whose result type is void
        return creditcard;
               ^
2 errors

```
import java.util.*; // so that I can use Scanner

public class Project1{
public static void main(String[] arg){
    String creditcard=mainintro();
    checksize(creditcard);
    checkprefix(creditcard);
}

public static void mainintro(){//Displays the intro message
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a credit card number from 13 to 16 digits      long:");
    String creditcard = console.next();
    return creditcard;
}

public static void checksize(String size){

int stringsize=size.length();//The Length of the creditcard

if(stringsize>=17||stringsize<=12){//Checks the size
System.out.println("The Credit card must be 13 to 16 numbers.");
System.out.println("");
System.out.println(size);
mainintro();
}else{System.out.println(size);}

}

public static void checkprefix(String creditcard){
System.out.println(creditcard);
}
}
```

If I define String creditcard=""; in main it works but only uses the "" as the variable? how can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like homework, so should probably be tagged as such.  Have you looked up the meaning of the "void" type?  Understanding that should give you an idea of why you're getting the error on trying to return a value from a void function.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
public static void mainintro()
```

To:

```
public static String mainintro()
```